# Jquery Datatables v1.9.2 paging not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I can't get the paging to render or work correctly on a jquery datatable version 1.9.2.

Here's the table init:

```
var tblResults = $('#tblResults').dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("LoadResults", "jQueryDataTable")?id=' + '@Model.itemId',
            "bFilter": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "bInfo": true,
            "sDom": 'ifrtlp',// '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"l>p<"clear">',
            "oLanguage": {
                "sZeroRecords": "No records found",
                "sInfoEmpty": "",
                "sInfo": "Showing _START_ - _END_ of  _TOTAL_ records",
            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
                                { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [1] },
                                { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [2] },
                                { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [3] }]
        });
```

The table loads correctly but the paging buttons over lap the length drop down.

[image]

The "Previous", "1", and "Next" options in the image are not clickable and i would like those options moved to the right with space after length.

What do i need to do to make those paging buttons work and align to the right?

Comment: maybe you should correct your table structure first and then those dynamic fields will be fixed automatically!

Comment: Side note: I would strongly recommend using the latest version of DataTables, if at all possible. v1.9.2 is relatively old - and there have been many changes, fixes and improvements since that release.

Comment: I updated to version 1.10.24 but the paging buttons still don't work

Comment: I think this is a "simple" CSS conflict. Try to detect the overrided rules with  browser DevTools

Comment: Yes, that was the case.  thank you for your help